# Improper Computation of NDVI in Android

Tags: android, image, image-processing, camera

I am new to image processing. I am trying to implement NDVI index on an image of agricultural farm in Android. But, I am unable to get the desired result.

Original Image:

[image]

I am using this code snippet to compute NDVI:

```
public int[][] applyNDVI(int[][] src1, int[][] src2) {

        final int pixels[][] = new int[width][height];
        
        

        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                //src1 is the image in red channel and src2 is the image in the blue channel.
                final int pixel1 = src1[i][j];
                final int pixel2 = src2[i][j];

                final double X = (pixel2 - pixel1);
                final double Y = (pixel2 + pixel1);

                double Z = (X / Y);

                //double Z = ((double)pixel1/(double)pixel2);

                int NDVI;
                NDVI = (int) (Z * 255);

                
                pixels[i][j] = Color.argb(Color.alpha(pixel1), NDVI, NDVI, NDVI);
       }
    }
    return pixels;
}
```

This code snippet is giving me this output:

[image]

From what I have read about NDVI, vegetation has a higher value of NDVI (between 0.2 and 0.9) as compared to barren/dry ground (<0.2). So, plants should be light grey and ground should be dark grey in the NDVI image. But I am getting and exactly opposite image.

Also when I am using a different NDVI formula i.e. NDVI = Red Channel / Blue Channel`i.e.

double Z = ((double)pixel1/(double)pixel2);`

This formula gives me the desired output (almost).

[image]

So, I am unable to understand this discrepancy. Also, I want to know if the NDVI formula depends on the camera used and the image taken? Or is the formula of NDVI universal? If it is universal, where am I going wrong and why am not I able to get the desired output. Any kind of help would be deeply appreciated.